# File redirection vs dd

Tags: bash, dd, pipe

Suppose I want to pipe the output of some command into a file. Is there any difference, however small or nuanced, between simply...well, piping it to a file like

```bsh
some-command > file
```

and piping it through `dd` like

```bsh
some-command | dd $MAYBE_SOME_OPTIONS_LIKE_BS of=file
```

This question is primarily to satisfy my curiosity, and unless the latter form has some non-negligible benefit or use case, in practice I would spare my fingers the exercise and go for the former.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Direct access to `file`

> ```
> some-command > file
> some-command | dd $MAYBE_SOME_OPTIONS_LIKE_BS of=file
> ```

In the first case `some-command` knows it writes to `file`, so it can retrieve metadata (like mtime or size) for whatever reason. Such metadata have useful meaning for regular files but for a unnamed pipe they are rather meaningless.

`some-command` may even be interested in opening what its stdout points to for reading, which is rather safe for regular files and obviously not the right thing to do in your second case.

But these scenarios are quite rare, I think.

---

#### Seekable vs non-seekable

The behavior of `some-command` may depend on whether its stdout is seekable or not. It's usually not the case, although it's possible. A regular file is seekable (you can read/write at any location). A pipe is not seekable.

`dd` itself is a valid example. Consider `some-command` being `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1 seek=1`. Your two examples become:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1 seek=1 > file
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1 seek=1 | dd of=file
```

The first command will work, it will leave `file` with two null bytes in it. In the second command the first `dd` will complain it cannot seek, it will exit; the second `dd` will get nothing, write nothing and exit without error.

I admit with `seek` this is not exactly plain "piping the output of some command into a file". But in general `some-command` may detect if its stdout is seekable and then stream different output *without* actually seeking. This shell function kinda does it as a proof of concept:

```
is-seekable() {
  if </dev/null dd bs=1 count=0 seek=1 conv=notrunc 2>/dev/null; then
    echo seekable
  else
    echo non-seekable
  fi
  }
```

Try these and examine the file after each one:

```
is-seekable > file
is-seekable | dd of=file
```

---

Knowing all the above, there's a scenario in which I would consider your second command: if `some-command` indeed behaves differently in two cases (like our `is-seekable` function) and I want it to "think" it's writing to a pipe but I want the output in a file. Then yes. Although I would rather use `cat` instead of `dd` (it probably wouldn't matter). E.g. I may want to get `non-seekable` from `is-seekable` and write it to a file:

```
is-seekable | cat > file
```

But only if it makes any difference. Otherwise it would be (in)famous "useless use of `cat`". Or in your case "useless use of `dd`"; or even "harmful use" if you handle the exit status poorly.

---

#### Exit status

Now try these two examples:

```
false > file
false | dd of=file
```

If you check `$?` after the second one, you will discover it's `0` (unless `dd` failed). Your second case discards the exit status of `some-command` (usually; e.g. in Bash investigate `set -o pipefail`, which is not portable).

So in the second case `some-command` may fail for whatever reason and you (or rather the logic of your script) will not know it. This is enough to *avoid* unnecessary piping to `dd` (or unnecessary piping at all).

---

#### Permissions

Another nuance: `some-command > file` makes the (sub)shell open the file before `some-command` is spawned (exec-ed to); `dd of=file` opens the file on its own behalf.

There are ways to grant more access rights to `dd` than to any other "regular" command. In other words there are ways to make plain `dd` behave more like `sudo dd` without password. You shouldn't do it and hopefully nobody does, yet it's possible.

What you can do is granting access rights on demand: `sudo dd`. It can be useful when trying to write to a restricted file. Analyze this:

```
some-command > restricted_file               # doesn't work
sudo some-command > restricted_file          # doesn't work
some-command | sudo dd > restricted_file     # doesn't work
sudo sh -c 'some_command > restricted_file'  # works, but it runs some_command as root
                                             #  you may not want this
some-command | sudo dd of=restricted_file    # works
some-command | sudo tee restricted_file      # works, more common, possibly with
                                             #  > /dev/null to suppress output to tty
```

I think this is very close to "non-negligible benefit or use case".

---

#### Maybe some options

Obviously `$MAYBE_SOME_OPTIONS_LIKE_BS` can alter `dd` behavior. I understand that options like `conv=swab` are out of scope because you want `file` to receive same data in both cases.

Still there are few options that can make a difference. Examples:

- `status=progress` will print the transfer rate and volume statistics on stderr, when processing each input block;
- `oflag=noatime` will not update the file's access timestamp;
- `oflag=nolinks` will fail if the file has multiple hard links;
- and [more](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html#dd-invocation).

The above examples are GNU extensions, not portable. Portable `dd` is characterized [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html).

---

#### KISS

Finally there's the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle): keep it stupid simple. Your first case is stupid simple.

Comment: A very detailed answer for a small question! One more thing I'm curious about is the way the file gets allocated (if there is a difference at all). I know on filesystems like `ext4`, it doesn't really matter, but anywhere it would or could possibly matter, what if I did something like, say, give `dd` a block size (which is why I hinted to it)? Obviously, if I really wanted to pre-allocate a file, I would use `fallocate` or something.

Answer (score 1):

No user should notice any differences. From a performance standpoint, doubt there will be a difference too. If you think of both scenarios, there's pros and cons but these depend heavily on what you're trying to accomplish.

For example:
cat file | dd of=file2 vs cat file > file2.
The difference here is, cat will open a file, dd will inherit the stream unless you specify a block size or some sort of writing flag, it'll start writing to the fs stack immediately.

If you don't use any features from dd, you're pretty much just forking a middle man, adding a process, this double fork I assume would have minimal performance loss vs just letting dd handle if=file of=newfile. The advantage, in this case, is, you can seek/skip in dd and well, there's only one process.

If you mean strictly just file redirection vs dd, I'd say there's no difference if you don't supply dd with any flags/parameters. You could use in this case as a middle man buffer, but there are way better alternatives, for example:
cat file | buffer | gzip > gzipped content.
For example, the above-stacked call, let's say you have a super quick source, and a slow destination, with the buffer in between you can make sure the receiving side always has a busy input queue, and if you're compressing you can make sure to keep your CPU from waiting for IO.

Again, all edge cases, that would require separate questions, but as you see, if we speak strictly from one vs the other one, even if there was a difference, doubt it'd be noticeable except for extreme edge cases.

Hope this helps, this question was quite interesting I have to say, took me a while to think about it.

Comment: +1 for the mention of `buffer`, because I had forgotten that was a thing.

Comment: Speaking of which, on a system without `buffer`, can `dd` with a block size act as a temporary hacky solution?

Comment: Actually yes, you should be able to use the block size as a really hacky buffer. I'd suggest against it since it won't really add that much performance and buffer is a better-suited solution. I loved the question lol really made me think a lot. The best way's I've seen this type of piping used is in conjunction with `pv` to see progress. Also when compressing streams, buffer and pv become super useful.

Comment: What makes `buffer` faster? Some kind of low-level optimization quirk?

Comment: Correct, `dd` has more control structures than `buffer` does. That being said, if anyone can notice the difference, I'll be incredibly shocked. I guess I just prefer the Linux motto of having specific applications for specific usage. Getting used to buffer and dd for their purpose I think is best. Don't forget that with `buffer` you get really useful parameters  to manage exactly that. With `dd` you're kind of hammering a nail with a screw driver.